# My website is looking good on iphone but its not detecting the window size for android phone?

Tags: reactjs

I have developed the website in react and using the semantic-ui-react components.
Have wrote the below code in render method for resizing the website for mobile.

```
let mobile = false;
let tablet = false;
let computer = false;

if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.document) {
  mobile = window.innerWidth < 500;
  tablet = window.innerWidth > 500 && window.innerWidth < 986;
  computer = window.innerWidth > 986;
```

I want the web pages should look good on android/Samsung phone also,
Now when i open on android phone it is taking the same view as computer but when i open on iPhone its taking the mobile view and renders website properly.

Comment: Do you have something like this in your HTML <head> ? : `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: Probably not your problem, but right now, if the window is exactly 500 or 986, nothing happens.

Comment: No i didn't use any html, everything in react js

Comment: Yes, I do have this <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />